# How can I reference acronyms using this template?

Tags: glossaries, acronyms, nomenclature, acro

I was wondering how I can use this script (mostly for the way it styles the Nomenclature section because I know I can use `\acrshort` etc.) in combination with referring to the symbols and acronyms within the body of the report? The script and the 'styled nomenclature' can be seen below.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\MySymbol[3]{\makebox[0.2\textwidth][l]{#1} \makebox[0.6\textwidth][l]{#2} \makebox[0.2\textwidth][l]{[#3]}\\[0.5em]}

\newcommand\MyAcronym[2]{\makebox[0.2\textwidth][l]{#1} \makebox[0.6\textwidth][l]{#2}\\[0.5em]}

\section{Nomenclature} 

\subsection*{List of Symbols}

\MySymbol{$A$}{Frontal surface area vehicle}{m\textsuperscript{2}}

\subsection*{Acronyms}

\MyAcronym{ARMA}{Auto Regressive Moving Average}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So what exactly are you looking for? You want a list of symbols and acronyms that look like what you already have? Well you already have that.

Comment: Yes, you're right I have that now. But I have no way of using them in the text, like you would normally do with \acrshort or another command. So I don't know what command to use to refer to these acronyms and symbols or what I need to do so I can do that.

Comment: Well your code defines nothing for referencing, and unless your usage is incredibly simple you probably want to use a package like [`acro`](https://ctan.org/pkg/acro) or [`glossaries`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) to handle acronyms etc.